# Pandas: Extract maximum from 2D data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
0   20  val option
0   2.0 11.0    0   option1
1   14.0    13.0    0   option2
2   17.0    2.0 0   option3
3   10.0    16.0    180 option1
4   15.0    12.0    180 option2
5   3.0 5.0 180 option3
```

I would like to find the "option" that maximizes the value at the left of the dataframe (column 0 and 20) for each of the "val" column. In other words, I would like to end up with this dataframe:

```
val 0   20
0   0   option3 option2
1   180 option2 option1
```

I tried the following, melting the dataframe and finding the indices that correspond to the maximum:

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df,id_vars=["val","option"],var_name="range",value_name="score")

val option  range   score
0   0   option1 0   2.0
1   0   option2 0   14.0
2   0   option3 0   17.0
3   180 option1 0   10.0
4   180 option2 0   15.0
5   180 option3 0   3.0
6   0   option1 20  11.0
7   0   option2 20  13.0
8   0   option3 20  2.0
9   180 option1 20  16.0
10  180 option2 20  12.0
11  180 option3 20  5.0

idx = df_melt.groupby(["val","range"]).idxmax()

score
val range   
0   0   2
20  7
180 0   4
20  9
```

This is successfully giving me the indices that matches with the best score. However, I dont know how to replace the indices by the "option" value
I tried doing:

```
df.loc[idx]
```

But this give me the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: As requested, here is how I generate the dataframe so you can reproduce the case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_twa = 2
n_tws = 2

sail = ["option1","option2","option3"]
TWA = sorted(len(sail)*np.linspace(0,180,n_twa,dtype=int).tolist())
sail = n_twa*sail
tws_range = np.linspace(0,20,n_tws,dtype=int)

col_dict = {tws:np.around(np.random.rand(1,len(sail))*20,0).flatten().tolist() for tws in tws_range}
col_dict["val"] = TWA
col_dict["option"] = sail

df = pd.DataFrame(col_dict)
```

Comment: can you provide your data in a dictionary form because it is hard to understand

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using your code to generate df getting this (as you code uses random numbers it is different from yours):

```
      0    20    val  option
--  ---  ----  -----  --------
 0   12     4      0  option1
 1    6     8      0  option2
 2    5     1      0  option3
 3   11     1    180  option1
 4    8     1    180  option2
 5    8    15    180  option3
```

We group `df` by `'val'` and then apply an aggregation `'idxmax'` to columns 0,20 (and drop column `val` eventually):

```
(df.groupby('val')
    .apply(lambda d: d.set_index('option').agg('idxmax'))
    .drop(columns = 'val')
)
```

this produces what is required:

```
    0       20
val     
0   option1 option2
180 option1 option3
```

Comment: Works fine, great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understand what you're looking for. But if you're looking for how to find the max in each `option`. You could try this:

```
df.groupby('option').max()
```

The result is:

> 0   20  val
> option1 19.0    8.0 180
> option2 10.0    15.0    180
> option3 13.0    16.0    180